# Update value in table, with comma seperated values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some contents that are sent to me with `php://input` that looks like this:

```
123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187
```

And I want to update a table based on this, so something like this

```
UPDATE char_
SET id=123
WHERE SortNumber=1
```

Now, I think I can do something like this

```
$variable=123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187
$anothervariable=$variable = str_replace(",", "\r\n", $variable); 


$i=0;
$i++;

 mysqli_query(UPDATE char_ SET id=$anothervariable WHERE SortNumber=$i)
```

But, I'm not sure that the code is 100 correct AND, the variable will be the whole contents and I dont know how I can set a different variable to every line? Any help?

Comment: Unless you're using a custom function, this is invalid `mysql_queryi`

Comment: I meant `mysqli_query` sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about PHP but can give you a rough idea with a sample pseudo code. Store all those numbers in a array (probably integer array) and loop through the array and call the `UPDATE` statement. Hope that makes sense

```
int[] arr = {123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187};

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  UPDATE char_ SET id=arr[$i] WHERE SortNumber=$i
}
```

Comment: Ok, these numbers are different everytime.

Comment: @ArtjomB., let them be; the sole point here is .. store those number in a array and then call the UPDATE statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understood well.. but i think the first word is no1 the second is no2, and so on... maybe that will bring up a solution to you.

```
$variable = "123,456,789";
$input_array = explode(',',$variable);

$c = 1;

foreach($input_array as $var) {

$query = 'UPDATE char_ SET value=$var WHERE SortNumber=$c';
$c++;

}
```

Comment: I've got you xd Always use prepared statements :P  
    `$variable = "123,456,789";
    $input_array = explode(',',$variable);
    
    $c = 1;
    
    foreach($input_array as $var) {
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query = "UPDATE char_ SET value=? WHERE SortNumber=?"))
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $var,$
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die('Error when inserting:'.mysqli_error($connection));
     }else{
          die('Error when preparing '.mysqli_error($connection));
          }
    }`